# Python CSV Pandas DataFrame.to_string() is not reading complete column value

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, tostring

I am using Pandas v0.20.1, trying to import CSV file and convert few columns to string. My CSV file columns are about 200+ characters, I want to convert these columns to string and print. I am suspecting that the function `df['Content'].to_string(header=False,index=False)` is culprit, as import is happening as expected, reading every each line. I will put an example with 1 big column.

example.csv

```
ID, Content
1, I am the big column with more than 50 characters to produce an example for question
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

dataFrame = pd.read_csv('example.csv')
print("Before modifying pd.options.display.max_colwidth")
print(dataFrame)
string1 = df['Content'].to_string(header=False,index=False)
print(string1)

print("After modifying pd.options.display.max_colwidth to some big value")
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 500
print(dataFrame)
print(string1)
string2 = df['Content'].to_string(header=False,index=False)
print(string2)
```

Output:

```
Before modifying pd.options.display.max_colwidth
   ID                                            Content
0   1  I am the big column with more than 50 characte...
I am the big column with more than 50 characte...

After modifying pd.options.display.max_colwidth to some big value
   ID                                            Content
0   1 I am the big column with more than 50 characters to produce an example for question  
I am the big column with more than 50 characte...
I am the big column with more than 50 characters to produce an example for question
```

The `string1` will be same even after changing max_colwidth value.
What I am really worried about is `to_string()`, is its behavior depends on `pd.options.display.max_colwidth` value? Or something else from `DataFrame` side?

If any other alternative to `to_string()` which will return me complete string value?

Comment: It's a pandas option, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html) to increase the column widths and the dupe answer

Comment: Thanks, @EdChum but what I need is the behavior of to_string(). Is that how it is defined? Sometimes you don't know the max length of the column to set `options.display.max_colwidth`.

Comment: If you set `max_colwidth` to `-1` then it will force it to display the full length, but really you shouldn't because if you have a very large df, then it's possible that the length of the output will kill your display buffer or make it hang, you can set it to something like 100 or 200 but anymore may make it unwieldy

Comment: Great, Thanks again..